# FIXED Many to many relationship, Invalid column name FIXED

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship  between House and Tenants. 
I am a little confused how to work it all out, the debugger is saying my column name is
Tenants_TenantID but its not, its TenantID ?

My Error

{"Invalid column name 'Tenants_TenantID'.\r\nInvalid column name 'House_HouseID'."}

Where my Error comes from

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddRole", "Role", new { houseId = @Model.HouseID }))
 {
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Select to Add Item</td>
            <td>
               <div class="editor-field">
              @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.TenantID, ((IEnumerable<FlatSystem.Models.Tenants>)ViewBag.TenantLookupList).Select(option => new SelectListItem
                {
                 Text = Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => option).ToString(),
                 Value = option.TenantID.ToString(),
                 Selected = (Model != null)
                 }), "Choose...")


              </div>
            </td>
           <td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
 }
```

FIXED

I fixed this problem 
By updating my DBContext file.

I made a simple mistake and missed out the DbSet for the 3rd table for my Many to Many to relationship

Comment: N to N relationships give rise to a third table (in your case House_Tenants) that will contain a primary key itself and "inherit" the keys of the other two tables involved. Just right there?

Comment: I think PiLHA is saying the 3rd table will have columns matching the column names in your error message. (At least in NHibernate that's the same naming convention).